# Awk scripts to read rows in a column with the same value and print/sort these rows based on date

Tags: bash, csv, awk

If we have a csv input here

Code:

```
Apple_ID, FDA_ID,Date, FDA_approved 
567,3, “2008-10-12  12:00:00 AM”,approved
567,2, “2008-10-12  12:00:00 AM”,approved
567,2, “2009-10-12  12:00:00 AM”,approved
348,1, “2008-10-12  12:00:00 AM”,approved
```

And we like to read the first column, if the Apple_ID is the same (567 for example) AND FDA_ID (1,2,3 for example) is different, print the row with the most recent Date (567,2, “10/12/2009 12:00:00 AM” in this case).

In this case, the desire output would be:

Code:

```
Apple_ID, FDA_ID,Date, FDA_approved 
348,1, “2008-10-12  12:00:00 AM”,approved
567,2, “2008-10-12  12:00:00 AM”,approved
567,2, “2009-10-12  12:00:00 AM”,approved
```

We try to write some arrays using the examples in other posts but doesn’t seem to work.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questi...r-column-value

Any hint could be quite helpful. Thanks!

Comment: The link to the `Unix & Linux` forum does not work.

Comment: Does your file really have those funky quotes, or are they actually normal double quotes?

Comment: these are normal double quotes for csv files: "2006-02-02 00:00:00"

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution. You did not specify what to do if the FDA_ID was *not* different.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use Text::CSV;

my $format = 'DateTime::Format::Strptime'->new(pattern => '%m/%d/%Y  %r');

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({allow_whitespace => 1,
                            eol => "\n",
                           });
open my $IN, '<', shift or die $!;
<$IN>; # Skip the header line.

my %min;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($IN)) {
    my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($row->[2]);
    $min{ $row->[0] } = { DT => $dt, FDA => $row->[1] }
        if ! exists $min{ $row->[0] }
        or 1 == 'DateTime'->compare($dt, $min{ $row->[0] }{DT});
}

for my $id (keys %min) {
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, [ $id,
                           $min{$id}{FDA},
                           $format->format_datetime($min{$id}{DT})
                         ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi choroba, thanks for your kind solutions.  May we know which version of your perl you use? Never use perl before and would love to download, install and learn it.  Thanks!

Comment: @HenrySu: It should work in any Perl version that is supported by the libraries, so I'd say 5.8+. You probably already have one installed on your system, if you're not on a MS Win.

Answer (score 2):

The challenge in what you are wanting to do is due to the requirement that you want output sorted by a date string in descending value. That is not terribly difficult, but will involve several steps to get the date element in a format that can be sorted. While 'awk' may well be able to handle that in some way, I would suggest you read the information into an array in BASH (2 actually), sort descending by date and then print the line array out (as many elements as desired)

The pseudo code will work as follows

```
declare -a datearray
declare -a linearray
let index=0

#read file into 2 arrays, one containing full line, other containing just date
while read -a linearray || [[ -n ${linearray[index]} ]]; do
    tmp=${linearray[index]}
    datearray[index]=`date -u -d "${tmp##*,}" +'%s'`  #store in date format
    ((index++))
done < $datafilename

    # sort descending based on `date -s ${datearray[index]}`
      (update linearray index in sort of datearray as datearray is sorted)
    # print using for loop the number of values desired
```

The `date -s` call will provide the date as the number of seconds since the epoch allowing a straight numerical sort using your chosen sort method (bubble-sort), etc... You will need to code the sort so that the linearray index is updated at the same time the datearray is sorted (to preserve the correlation between linearray and datearray in order to result in a sorted linearray) If you run into problems, post your code and we can work with your further. Good luck with the actual code.

Here is a cobbled together sort routine that will sort based on datearray and produce a sorted linearray. Double check it.

```
## function sort integer array (hacked for datearray & linearray)
sort_int_array() {
    local sz=${#datearray[@]}
    test "$sz" -lt 2 && { echo "$FUNCNAME() warning: datearray '$sz' unable to sort"; return 1; }
    local _tmp
    local _tmpline
    for((i=0;i<$sz;i++)); do
        for((j=$((sz-1));j>i;j--)); do
        ## read modified with date format +'%s' filling array with seconds since epoch
        [[ ${datearray[$i]} -gt ${datearray[$j]} ]] && {
        # [[ `date -s ${datearray[$i]}` -gt `date -s ${datearray[$j]}` ]] && {
            _tmp=${datearray[$i]}
            _tmpline=${linearray[$i]}
            datearray[$i]=${datearray[$j]}
            linearray[$i]=${linearray[$j]}
            datearray[$j]=$_tmp
            linearray[$j]=$_tmpline
        }
        done
    done
    unset _tmp      # unsetting is unnecessary, local vars only have function
    unset _tmpline  # scope, but left as a reminder to always unset variables
    unset sz        # that are no longer needed
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the hint!  However, couple questions: (1) let index=0 is to just to clean the "index" variable as 0?   (2) `date -u -d "${tmp##*,}"` do you mean "date -u -d ${tmp}"? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `let date=0` just cleans it and quasi tells BASH it is an integer (even though BASH is untyped).  `"${tmp##*,}"` removes all characters from the string up to and including the last `,` isolating the date for `datearray[index]`. You can also do it with `datearray[index]=${tmp//*,/}`. If you get stuck on the sort, I have a sort routine that will work. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @HenrySu Note I modified the read loop with `date -u -d "${tmp##*,}" +'%s'` eliminating the need to call date in the sort function as the datearray elements are then filled with number of seconds since epoch.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` and  `sort` you can do:

```
sort -k2 file | awk -F, '/^Apple/ {h=$0;next} {a[$1]=$0} END {print h;for (i in a) print a[i]}'
Apple_ID, FDA_ID,Date
567,2, .2009-10-12  12:00:00 AM.
348,1, .2008-10-12  12:00:00 AM.
```

If you like output to be `sorted`

```
sort -k2 file | awk -F, '/^Apple/ {h=$0;next} {a[$1]=$0} END {print h;for (i in a) print a[i] | "sort"}'
Apple_ID, FDA_ID,Date
348,1, .2008-10-12  12:00:00 AM.
567,2, .2009-10-12  12:00:00 AM.
```

Comment: Hi Jotne, elegant awk lines! My understand is if the first column is "Apple" (/^Apple/), read the whole header line and immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record {h=$0;next}.  {a[$1]=$0} read the whole data lines into an array. END. Print header (print h) and print sorted data {for (i in a) print a[i] | "sort"}

Comment: I change the question a little bit. What if we need to keep rows with the most updated "FDA_ID"? In this case, both rows with {567,2} should be kept because FDA_ID=2 has a 2009 data.

Comment: @HenrySu Just change `{a[$1]=$0}` to `{a[$2]=$0}`

Comment: Hmmm changing {a[$1]=$0} to {a[$2]=$0} doesn't seem to work.  It  only keeps a row with each unique FDA_ID.

Comment: @HenrySu Give example output in your original post, so I can see how you like it.

Comment: May I know if you might have any comment, Jotne?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    f_gen = tuple(x for x in (tuple(field.strip()
                  for field in lines.split(','))
                  for lines in f.readlines()))
    matches = {}
    multiples = []
    h = 0
    for field in f_gen:
        if h == 0:
            header = ','.join(field)
            h = 1
            continue

        if field[0] in multiples:
            continue
        else:
            dups = [x for x in f_gen if x[0] == field[0]]
            date = [x[2] for x in dups if x[0] == field[0]]
            if len(date) > 1:
                date.sort()
                multiples.append(field[0])

            for dup in dups:
                if dup[0] == field[0] and date[-1] == dup[2]:
                    matches[dup[0]]="%s,%s,%s" % (dup[0],dup[1],dup[2])

print(header)
for match in matches:
    print(matches[match])
```

Output:

```
Apple_ID,FDA_ID,Date
348,1,"2008-10-12  12:00:00 AM"
567,2,"2009-10-12  12:00:00 AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the apple id would be same then One more way to get desired result  using awk and sort:

```
sort -k2 apple.csv|  awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}; {count++; if($1~/567/){result=$0}else{head=$0}} END{if(count==NR){print head,"\n",result}}'
```

This will give you result:

Apple_ID, FDA_ID,Date
 567,2, “2009-10-12  12:00:00 AM”

PS: apple.csv is input file.